# Sieve of Eratosthenes implementation

Tags: c++, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I am trying to implement algorithm for Sieve of Eratosthenes but I don't know why this program crashes for larger programs. Initially I was using `vector` but now I am implementing this using dynamic memory allocation.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

unsigned isqrt(unsigned value) {
  return static_cast<unsigned>(sqrt(static_cast<float>(value)));
}

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    long long * N;
    long long * M;
    long long n, m;
    N = new long long[t];
    M = new long long[t];
    for(int i = 0; i < t ; i++){
        cin >> M[i] >> N[i];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < t ; i++){
        n = N[i];
        m = M[i];

        bool * A;
        A = new bool[n];
        if(A == 0)
        {
            cout << "Memory cannot be allocated";
            return 0;
        }

        for(int i=0;i < n;i++){
            A[i]=true;
        }
        A[0] = false;
        A[1] = false;

        unsigned sqrt = isqrt(n);
        for(int i = 2; i <= sqrt; i++)
        {
            if(A[i] == true){
                for(int j = i*i; j <= n; j = j + i)
                {
                    A[j] = false;
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i = m;i < n;i++)
        {
            if(A[i] == true )
                cout << i << "\n";
        }

        delete[] A;
    }

    delete[] M;
    delete[] N;
    return 0;
}
```

The program crashes for larger values of `n` and `m` (~10^16). Kindly help me out.

Comment: I don't see neither a question, nor a problem/error.

Comment: program crushes - not a problem?

Comment: `unsigned sqrt = isqrt(n)` is **wrong**. recalculating the sieve for each input pair is redundant. it should be calculated only once.

Comment: You do realize that even the highly optimized multi-threading [primesieve](http://primesieve.org/), which is a version of the Sieve of Eratosthenes written in C, will take something in the order of a month to sieve the primes to 10^16 on a modern desktop computer?  That code is Open Source so you can read it, but you'll find it quite complex to accomplish what it does.  You'll find you need to write hundreds of lines of code (and learn a lot of techniques and algorithms) to come anywhere close.

Comment: Note also that in order to calculate several ranges of primes, as seems to be your intention here, does not require that one sieves the whole range of primes to the top prime index, but rather only to the square root of the top prime index then use a segmented paged sieve to sieve over the desired range, as does primesieve.

Comment: Finally, you don't state to what purpose you intend for this huge list of primes (to 10^16); if you only need to know the count of the primes to that limit, the sum of the primes to that limit, or the highest prime less than that limit, there are numerical analysis algorithms that will reduce the time as compared to using a sieve from months to minutes.  However, finding maximum gaps between primes or the occurrence of prime twins, triplets, and so on needs to be done with a sieve.

Answer (score 4):

```
for(int j = i*i; j <= n; j = j + i)
                   ^^
```

If `j == n` then `A[j] = false` will assign to an element past the end of the array. The test should be `j < n`.

Comment: But why does that happen only for larger values of m and n, not for small values?

Comment: @mozart Illegally accessing memory causes undefined behavior in C++. The results of undefined behavior are not necessarily predictable. This is different from languages like Java and Python which almost always crash in a predictable and consistent way.

Comment: so standard, this should be prohibited

Comment: @cf16, if you're saying that invalid accesses should be trapped somehow you're missing one of the benefits of C++ - it doesn't waste time checking the index before each access. If you need that kind of hand-holding choose a different language and expect it to run slower.

Comment: @MarkRansom: You *can* get that sort of hand-holding in C++ if you want. Just for example, using `std::vector` with `at()` will check all accesses.

Comment: @MarkRansom I was just kidding, I really like illegal accesses : p

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to write a sieve of Eratosthenes in C++, how about if you actually *use* C++, not try to treat it as some demented cross between C and assembly language.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

unsigned long primes = 0;

int main() {
    int number = 10000000;
    std::vector<bool> sieve(number,false);
    sieve[0] = sieve[1] = true;

    for(int i = 2; i<number; i++) {
        if(!sieve[i]) {
            ++primes;
            for (int temp = 2*i; temp<number; temp += i)
                sieve[temp] = true;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "found: " << primes << " Primes\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no problem in implementing it this way but the inputs are very large (~10^16) and that is why I thought of using pointers not `vector`.The template introduces extra overhead but I actually got to know that I have to implement a segmented Sieve of Eratosthenes for solving the problem.

Comment: @mozart: What overhead do you think the template adds? [Hint: it at least normally does rather the opposite, storing each bool as a single bit, where yours has to store each bool as a minimum of one byte.]

Comment: @SumitGera if m ~ 10^16, then its sqrt is ~ ... ? No, you don't need *segmented* sieve for this problem. The core sieve is not getting *extended*; you should calculate it only once, then sieve each of the *offset* segments separately, with the core primes.

Answer (score 1):

If n is big enough to cause memory allocation error program will crash due to incorrect memory allocation error handling here

```
 A = new bool[n];
        if(A == 0)
        {
            cout << "Memory cannot be allocated";
            return 0;
        }
```

new doesn't return 0 on error, but throws std::bad_alloc that doesn't get catched, which in turn will lead to unexpected() then terminate() and finally abort() to be called.
Correct version would be:

```
  try
  {
    A = new bool[n];
  }
  catch (std::bad_alloc& ba)
  {
    std::cerr << "Memory cannot be allocated: " << ba.what() << '\n';
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Run this in a debugger to determine where the crash is and debug from there.  It will most likely be apparent at that point.

You can do this either from an IDE or from command line.  In the latter case compile with `-g` and run in a program such as `gdb`.  Google something like "gdb cheatsheet" to get started.

Comment: How does SPOJ compiles and runs such problems? Its giving me SIGABRT. I don't see any reason of execution of function abort().

Comment: @mozart I don't know what SPOJ is.