# Prime number search algorithm (two different algorithm) and use of prime tables

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, mathematical-optimization

I've written two algorithms to find prime numbers. One - `isPrime()` - is based on searching for odd divisors from 3 till the square root of the odd numbers to analyze (the even numbers are discarded), the second - `isPrime2()` - is based on the assumption that all prime numbers greater than 3 have the form: p=k*6-1 or p=k*6+1. (These function consider the number 1 is a prime, but is easy to modify this behaviour if you think 1 is not a prime!)

The second algorithm is slightly faster than the first, but using tables they have at least the same speed.

Using tables (as the main(), below, does) the search becomes two times faster (searching for the first million of primes) than without using them. You may verify that fact modifying the calls to the `isPrime()` functions in the `while` loops as in the following:

```
isPrime(n, NULL);
```

instead of:

```
isPrime(n, &tbl[x]);
```

The main() loads two primes tables containing a million of primes, one using `isPrime()` and the other one using `isPrime2()`, then printout the used time and some primes. After that the main() compares the results of the two tables.

I'm interested in algorithms to fill prime numbers tables (also starting from 1) and to indentify if a big/huge number is a prime number. Have you suggestions? Do you know different or faster algorithms?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

typedef struct prime_table {
    uint64_t * primes;
    uint32_t inTable;
    uint32_t maxIn;
} table;

int isPrime(uint64_t n, table * t)
{
    uint64_t i, k, m;

    if(!n)
        return 0;

    if(n < 4)
        return 1;

    if(!(n & 1))    /* the number is even */
        return 0;

    m = sqrt(n);

    k = 1;
    if(t) {
        for(i = 2; i < t->inTable && t->primes[i] <= m; i++) {
            k = t->primes[i];
            if(!(n % k))
                return 0;
        }
    }

    k += 2;
    for(i = k; i <= m; i += 2) {
        if(!(n % i))
            return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

int isPrime2(uint64_t n, table * t)
{
    uint64_t i, k, m;

    if(!n)
        return 0;

    if(n < 4 || n == 5)
        return 1;

    if(!(n & 1))    /* the number is even */
        return 0;

    if(!(n % 3))
        return 0;

    k = (n - 1) / 6; m = (n + 1) / 6;
    if(k * 6 + 1 != n && m * 6 - 1 != n)
        return 0;

    m = sqrt(n);
    k = 5;
    if(t) {
        for(i = 3; i < t->inTable && t->primes[i] <= m; i++) {
            k = t->primes[i];

            if(!(n % k))
                return 0;
        }
    }
    k += 2;

    k = (k - 1) / 6; m = (m + 1) / 6;
    for(i = k; i <= m; i++) {
        if(!(n % (6 * i - 1)) || !(n % (6 * i + 1)))
            return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

uint32_t getusec()
{
    struct timeval t;
    gettimeofday(&t, NULL);

    return (t.tv_sec * 1000000UL + t.tv_usec);
}

int main(void)
{
    static table tbl[2];
    uint64_t n = 1;
    uint32_t t, i, j;

    /* Init two prime tables */
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        tbl[i].maxIn = 1000000;
        tbl[i].primes = malloc(tbl[i].maxIn * sizeof(*tbl[0].primes));

        /* Load the 1,2 and 3 into the table */
        for(j = 1; j < 4; j++)
            tbl[i].primes[j - 1] = j;

        tbl[i].inTable = 3;
    }

    /* Loading table with isPrime()*/
    t = getusec();
    n = 3;
    while(tbl[0].inTable < tbl[0].maxIn) {
        n += 2;
        if(isPrime(n, &tbl[0])) {
            tbl[0].primes[tbl[0].inTable++] = n;
        }
    }

    printf("%u primes computed in %u usec\n", tbl[0].inTable, getusec() - t);
    puts("First 16 computed primes");

    for(i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        printf("%9lu ", tbl[0].primes[i]);

    puts("\n--------------------");
    puts("Last 16 computed primes");

    for(i = tbl[0].inTable - 16; i < tbl[0].inTable; i++)
        printf("%9lu ", tbl[0].primes[i]);

    puts("\n--------------------");

    /* Loading table with isPrime2()*/
    t = getusec();
    n = 3;
    while(tbl[1].inTable < tbl[1].maxIn) {
        n += 2;
        if(isPrime2(n, &tbl[1])) {
            tbl[1].primes[tbl[1].inTable++] = n;
        }
    }

    printf("%u primes computed in %u usec\n", tbl[1].inTable, getusec() - t);
    puts("First 16 computed primes");

    for(i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        printf("%9lu ", tbl[1].primes[i]);

    puts("\n--------------------");
    puts("Last 16 computed primes");

    for(i = tbl[1].inTable - 16; i < tbl[1].inTable; i++)
        printf("%9lu ", tbl[1].primes[i]);

    puts("\n--------------------");
    puts("Searching for differences in tables");

    for(i = 0; i < tbl[0].inTable; i++) {
        if(tbl[0].primes[i] != tbl[1].primes[i]) {
            printf("%u %lu %lu", i, tbl[0].primes[i], tbl[1].primes[i]);
            break;
        }
    }

    if(i == tbl[0].inTable) {
        puts("No differences have been found!");
    }

    puts("--------------------");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This should be faster: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes if you search all primes starting from one to N. Implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980599/sieve-of-eratosthenes-implementation

Comment: I'm searching for solutions to generate tables (also starting from 1), and solution to verify if a big number is prime!

Answer (score 4):

Depending on input values, but if you want to get more efficient, a known solution is using the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

The sieve is similar to the concept of "check if there is an odd divisor" - why only odds? Because only even prime is 2. Similarly you could do it for 3,5 and any other prime number.

The sieve finds these prime dynamically, and discards all non primes that are influenced by each prime.

---

If you are looking for checking if a single huge number is prime, there is actually an efficient solution to it that runs in polynomial time of the number of bits representing the number (polynomial of the log of the number), which is known as [AKS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test)